# Server allowing only one request per session

Tags: php, session

**Scenario:**

All pages of xyz.com use sessions to check if I am logged in and display customized content.  I am logged into xyz.com using Firefox on my iMac. Now, when I try to visit, xyz.com/page1.php and xyz.com/page2.php at the same time, until page1 loads page2 is not processed.

**Code Samples**

xyz.com/contains (links):

```
/* session check code here */
Page1
Page2
```

xyz.com/page1.php contains:

```
/* session check code here */
echo "Hello";
flush();
sleep(5);
echo "done";
```

xyz.com/page2.php contains:

```
/* session check code here */
echo "Second Page";
/* {insert code} to log time() to log.txt */
```

**Testing**

Here's what I do. I login to shell and keep this command running:

```
user@xyz.com [~/public_html]# tail -f log.txt
```

From my browser (Firefox), (on xyz.com), I open multiple instances of page1 and page2 in tabs. If you can see, page1 will at least take 5 seconds to load. Now, until page 1 loads, request to page2 is pending. It's not at all processed. How do I know that? The code at the end of page2 logs access time to a file which I am monitoring. Let's consider the following case:

Requests fired to (in order)
1. page1.php 
2. page2.php
3. page2.php
4. page1.php
5. page1.php
6. page2.php

**Result (approx)**

1237961919 <-- #2
1237961920 <-- #3
1237961931 <-- #6

**What was expected (approx)**

1237961915 <-- #2
1237961915 <-- #3
1237961915 <-- #6

^Assuming that all calls were fired at the same time

**Observation**

While the calls are being processed, I am obviously not able to visit xyz.com as well (being another request). However, if I open it in another browser (Safari), it works well. That's because it's another session?

**Possible Causes**

1. The server has some security in place?

   > I am more of a coder but if someone can give pointers, I can check the server (VPS) to see if apache/php is misconfigured.
2. I am not handling sessions correctly?

   > Does it matter? Shouldn't the second request be processed as a different thread?
3. Aliens are controlling my VPS.

   > Ok, kidding. I am just tired of tracing this issue. Would really appreciate if anyone has any clue what could be going wrong here.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if u visit page1 and page2 using safari at the same time? Just to check if its ur browser issue.

Comment: Yes, happens on Safari too. I've tried it on other computers as well.

Comment: Your server is using file based sessions. When one request is pending, the session file is locked and the server will queue any later requests trying to use the same session. Switch to database-stored sessions and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your server is using file based sessions. When one request is pending, the session file is locked and the server will queue any later requests trying to use the same session.

Switch to database-stored sessions and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try to call `session_write_close()` in page1.php after you finished session check code.

```
/* session check code here */
session_write_close();
echo "Hello";
flush();
```

This should close the session file (remove the lock) and page2.php can open it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: Just to emphasis : this is important to flush() or send back some output to browser in order to get it working

Answer (score 1):

[check](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) your [network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server) and [network.http.max-connections-per-server](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections-per-server).

Comment: Thanks but it's not an FF issue.

Answer (score 0):

Never encountered anything like that. Are you sure you're not using CGI instead of FastCGI? Also check how many php processes your webserver spawns and how many requests they can handle each.

To help with testing you might want to put [sleep function](http://php.net/sleep) in test-page.

Comment: All these requests generated on the server, i.e., they appear as processes when I run top.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know for php, but with asp.net, the session object cannot be used in read/write by more than one thread at a time. So it produced something like you describe. The second request wait for the session state to be "unlocked" to start processing. It does makes sense, that way the session object is consistent for all the processing of the request.