# Execute multiple AJAX request parallel without waiting for others to respond

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading

I have the problem that i need to execute multiple AJAX requests
on one Page. The request start all at the same time but they seem to wait for their predecessor to return.

Lets say that page1 needs about 3 seconds to load. And page2 needs 2 seconds to load. What i get is that both start at the same time and the page1 request returns after 3 secons.

But the problem is that the page2 request returns after 5 seconds.
Why is that so ? I thought that every AJAX request will run in it's own thread. So why do the queue? Why does the second one waits for the first one to respond befor it even seem to start?

How do I manage to send both requests and process each respond as soon as it arrives ?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'page1.php',
    data: { }
})
.done(function( data ) {                
    console.log(data);
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'page2.php',
    data: { }
})
.done(function( data ) {                
    console.log(data);
});
```

I see a lot of examples using this approach.

```
$.when(
    $.get("/resource1"),
    $.get("/resource2"),
    $.get("/resource3")
).done(function(response1, response2, response3) {
// do things with response1, response2 and response3;
});
```

But as far as i understand this it will process the responses as soon as all of them returned.

Any ideas on this one ?

Comment: you need to add an extra property `async:true`.                                       If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.

Comment: `async:true` is default setting no need to set it up explicitly. @Manoz

Comment: Yep thats true, the async is by default true and i already tried this.

Comment: It's seems that you have not any answer for it.

Answer (score 6):

you first code sample guarantees to run the code when any AJAX request is completed and CPU is **free** to use. Do **NOT** forget the JS engine is **single thread** and it **queues** tasks to do when CPU is free.

if your first completed AJAX request (A1) takes 10 seconds to run and during this time the second AJAX request (A2) get completed, A2 has to wait because CPU is processing the code for A1.

You can find more details in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ. In this video Philip Roberts describes how event loops are working in browsers.

Comment: Ok this is pretty interesting. And i would understand this but to use your example. If A1 needs 10 seconds and lets say A2 needs 2 seconds and both were send at the same time why does A2 returns after 12 seconds and not as soon as A1 returns ?

Comment: I created simple sample in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fb1Lvbf6/2/). A1 takes 10 seconds to load and A2 takes 2 seconds. It seems A2 has been done first and the A1 after 8 seconds.

Comment: I understand this a bit better now. What may be the best solution for that problem ? How do i manage to load time consuming parts simultaniously ?

Comment: Ok your example runs exactly like I would expect it to run. A2 return after 2 seconds and A1 returns after 10 seconds. But if I try this with my own requested sources A1 would return after 10 seconds and A2 after 12 seconds. What can cause this behavior ? I don't get it...

Comment: I'm currently at the point that I'm assuming that our webserver might queue my requests. So maybe that is the actual problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Give async:true
The request will be processed invidually!

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'test.html',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) { alert(data); }
        });
```

Comment: as said in the comments above the async is true by default.

Comment: The response secs varies according to request and response size. async works only on whether you want to call the request simultaneously or one by one?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP and file-based sessions, you may be limited to a single request per (PHP) page. You must close the session for multiple requests to be processed at the same time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065977/1620112 for a solution to this.