# Execute multiple XHR request without waiting for each other

Tags: jquery, ajax

As the title said, I want to load 1 file with a long loading time on the background. If I click on another ajax request, it will wait for the first request to be fully loaded.

Is it possible to load blank.php (my test file) on the background so it won't affect other requests?
I already checked the following question:
[Execute multiple AJAX request parallel without waiting for others to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691648/execute-multiple-ajax-request-parallel-without-waiting-for-others-to-respond)
but it didn't gave me the answer...

At the image, you can see the last request (jobdetails.php) is waiting for blank.php to be loaded.

[image: XHR request]

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so it won't wait. Unless you've explicitly passed `async: false`, in which case - don't do that. The only other way the AJAX request might be running serial is if the *server* is what can't process them in parallel.

Comment: Use original `XMLHTTPRequest` or `fetch` to do that.

Comment: async is set true

Comment: Then there is nothing on the front-end that will prevent the requests running together. Once the network call is made, you're bound by the server's response not by anything client-side.

Comment: well is something on the PHP side causing it?

Comment: @epascarello might be, although it's also possible that it's just OP is getting the same order as the network calls come back. Perhaps with enough tries there would be a difference. It's also possible that it's "random" but stacked in favour of this order - the server might just need more time to process jobdetails.php than it does blank.php.

Comment: @epascarello PHP side is only running a sql request

Comment: Isn't it possible to load blank.php and send the request when it is fully loaded?

Comment: It *is* possible but aren't you asking for the opposite - do both requests at once?

Comment: @VLAZ I see I didn't ask it right xD What i ment is to load blank.php on the background and request the data when  it's fully loaded, but in the meantime I want to send other requests without waiting for blank.php

Comment: Again, there is nothing on the client-side that would prevent you from doing it. Once a back-end request is issued, everything you're waiting for is 1. the back-end to respond (server-side execution time matters) 2. the request to travel over the network back to you (network speed, bandwidth, and latency matter). JS itself won't limit the order of requests being processed.