# CodeIgniter Hangs Unexpectedly after echo large decrypted file

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-3

I'm creating controller to handle encrypted files and return decrypted files on server "Apache" like this

```
    if (array_key_exists($ext, $this->content_types)) {
        $content_type = $this->content_types[$ext];
        $file_content = $this->decrypt(file_get_contents($encrptedpath));
        header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);
        echo $file_content;
        exit;
    }
```

and here is the decrypt method inside my controller

```
    /**
 * Decrypt a string
 * 
 * @Param string &$data 
 * 
 * @return string  - original text   
 */
public static function decrypt($data)
{
    if (!is_string($data))
        throw new Exception("Invalid data"); // throw exception or exit

    $ivSize  = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::$_cypher);
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    $ivData   = substr($data, 0, $ivSize);
    $encData = substr($data, $ivSize);

    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
        $encData,
        self::$_cypher,
        self::$_key,
        OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
        $ivData
    );

    return $decrypted;
}
```

my issue is that after delivering the decrypted file "large video file" correctly to the player, the server hangs on any new request for a few minutes, and surprisingly it works immediately only if I open index.php file on root and type

```
echo "test"; exit;
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

and upload, request any Url and then remove that line and its back to normal

Comment: Check your logs

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing gets logged regarding that behavior

Answer (score 0):

thanks to this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680327/server-allowing-only-one-request-per-session/8065977) its was not related to decrytion it self, but the session is locked and the requests are queued until finish,
i used session_write_close(); before echo and ob_flush(); flush(); after